# I really like Road of Knives. Are there any rulesets that would make this game more complex?

Tags: game-recommendation

> Road of Knives is a "battle blog"
>   wherein Zak Smith, Shawn Cheng, and
>   other artists take turns drawing
>   monsters fighting each other.

from the website, [Road of Knives](http://www.roadofknives.com/)

I'm looking for similar games or rulesets that involve drawing each others' characters. Ideally, I'd like to know if there are any games with more complicated rule systems.

Comment: Reminder to all about our [System Recommendation policy](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a wonderful roleplaying game called [Sketch!](http://www.sjgames.com/pyramid/sample.html?id=1980) that does this exact thing. You draw/doodle the monster, and then the monsters battle. Once you draw something, it gets passed around and players vote on what it should have as far as stats and gear. I've had some fun with it in the past and highly recommend it, especially if you play with people who can draw or aren't afraid to draw crappily! (Drawing crappily is highly recommended actually)

Comment: I'm very disappointed that I can't seem to find this game for sale anywhere. But I would like to say that the game is lightweight enough that there wasn't much to the system anyway.

Comment: There is [one for trade at RPGGeek right now](http://www.rpggeek.com/collection/items/rpgitem/57155?fortrade=1).